# vh and vw don't work as expected in safari 11

Tags: html, css, safari

I'm trying to make a block that covers the whole screen, and it looks like safari 11 wouldn't let me do that through vh and vw.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div style="
    background-color: black;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh
    ">

    </div>
</body>
```

[Here's the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiR5a.png)

I'm kind of confused, because in safari 10 this code works fine.
I really need to know if this is a bug with safari or it's me doing something wrong.

safari version -- 11.0

Comment: Did you compare changes between these 2 versions of Safari? Maybe safari v11 does not support this behavior.

Comment: @ImantsVolkovs Honestly, haven't found anything about this problem. Even caniuse.com says that safari 11 does support vh, vw etc. However it does not work correctly

Comment: then maybe change the style to pixels :) Another thing, I guess you missed ';' at the end of height property